# Wireguard VPN not making handshake

Tags: security, vpn, openvpn, wireguard, network-security

I'm facing a trouble, I have a server with Wireguard configured, with the keys generated by wg command line.
I've downloaded Wireguard for windows and put the public's server key on client peer, and public's cliente key on server Peer section. Mu doubt is: is the client be configured to access server Endpoint external IP?
I tried point to external and internal (LAN) IP from client, but no way it works. I am using VirtualBox with this schemme:

Server: 1 nic - mode NAT; 1 nic - wg0 (wireguard)
Client windows 10: 1 nic - wg0 (wireguard). Does not have any other nic. It can be a problem?

[my schemme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3ao8.png)

Comment: If your client can't reach your server, how do you expect WG to work?

Comment: @vidarlo I dont know why not. Both have internal interfaces at the same network.

Comment: @FabricioFranco For me the problem was: the wrong Debian firewall config. After turning off the firewall (for test) the handshake error disappeared. There is a great auto-setup-script [here...](https://gitlab.com/snax44/wireguard-ui-setup) where you may analyse the `.sh` file for necessary `iptable` config commands.

Comment: @FabricioFranco Also I think setting NAT for VirtualBox makes it impossible to reach it as a server. You should at least set VB to "bridged" mode and route that IP from your own subnet to the router's outside port. Alternatively You may use a tiny separate hardware for that, like a RPi, instead if complicating with VB.